# How to edit-and-execute last two commands with `fc` in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, shell

I just learned about the `fc` builtin to bash. I want to use it to edit and execute the previous two commands, *including the most recent command*.

I can edit-and-execute two commands up to *but not including* the most recent command with `fc -2 0`. This is what I want, except offset by one to include the most recent command.

One workable but annoying solution is to examine the output of `history` (or `fc -l`), find the absolute command numbers, and give the command range in absolute terms. For example, if `fc -l -2` outputs the following:

```
502  echo hello
503  echo goodbye
```

…then I could say `fc 502 503`. This is what I want, except that I don't want the extra step of examining history output. (I know, I'm picky.)

Is there any way to do this that doesn't involve (1) manual examination of the history or (2) a throwaway command to bump the commands of interest out of the most recent spot?

I'm running `GNU bash version 3.2.57` on macOS, for what it's worth.

Comment: Does `fc -s -2; fc -s -1` work for you? It works on `bash` in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @AFH - Alas, no. The `-s` skips the editing step. (Plus I'd like to edit the two lines together.) Almost though. :-)

Comment: If you want to edit and execute, then miss out the `-s`, as in `fc -2; fc -1`.

Comment: Right, but I want to edit the two lines together. `fc -2; fc -1` edits and executes serially. Furthermore, for whatever reason, `fc -2; fc -1` edits the same command (number `-2`) twice, rather than the two most recent ones.

Comment: I get the same command twice only if I abort the first edit, but I can't work out why. It's not clear exactly what you want. Do you want to edit two commands in one edit? If this is what you want, then `fc -- -2 -1` appears to do this, as `--` makes all the following parameters positional, not options.

Comment: Yes, I want to edit two commands in one edit. (Specifically, I'm wanting to combine the two most recent commands using an editor.) When I try `fc -- -2 -1` as you suggest, I see two commands in my editor, but they are shifted one older and don't include the most recent command. Does `fc -- -2 -1` do something different for you? If so, which version of `bash` are you running?

Comment: I typed in sequence `echo a`, `echo b`, `echo c`, and `fc -- -2 -1`. The editor was launched on a temporary file containing the lines `echo b` and `echo c`, and on save and exit these two lines were executed. Ubuntu 16.04 shows my `bash` revision as `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)`.

Comment: Ah, very good! It looks like this was fixed in bash v4.3. I upgraded my bash version, and it works as you say. If you add an answer to this effect and include the following link, I will accept your answer. Thanks for working with me on this! http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES#n1223

Comment: I have submitted the answer, but I have referenced a different bug in the list: this seems better related to the problem you experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One would expect `fc -2 -1` to work, but there seems to be confusion between options and positional parameters which begin with `-`. However, using the standard `--` to separate options from parameters appears to offer a solution:

```
fc -- -2 -1
```

Note that versions of `bash` prior to 4.3. had other problems with the `fc` command, including [`fff.` here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES#n2994), where the history line selection can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This takes the id of the latest 2 commands and run them again

```
fc -l -2 | cut -f1 | fc -s
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't let me edit the commands before executing them. Thanks though!

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you bean by editing the command before executing them. Could you please be more clear about your edit requirements? E.g. you want to automatically open a text file with the latest 2 commands, edit it, save it, and run the commands in the text file.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. It's what the `fc` builtin does unless the `-l` or `-s` switch is specified.

Comment: then the comment of @AFH to your question seems the right answer to me